# "[: too many arguments" appears occasionally with pidof

Tags: shell

```
 cplane_pid=`pidof hnb_gw.exe`
    if [ -z $cplane_pid ]
    then
        STATUS=`failure`
        echo "Cplane hnbgw running     $STATUS"
    else
        STATUS=`success`
        echo "Cplane hnbgw running     $STATUS"
    fi      
    echo
```

Comment: Consider refactoring so that $STATUS is set in the if block and the echo comes after.

Answer (score 4):

If there are multiple instances of `hnb_gw.exe`, pidof will return multiple pids. The `-z` of `[` expects only one pid. One solution might be to use the `-s` switch of pidof to return only one pid.

Comment: actually, there will be two few arguments when it on the other hand returns none (`-z` just checks whether argument is empty); more quotes seem to be the better solution here

Comment: You are right in that quotes are better, but that was not the reason for the problem.

Comment: Well yes, it was. `-z` is not expecting just one pid. It is expecting exactly one, empty or non-empty argument. Thus getting only one pid is not what is wanted. Getting exactly one string is and that needs quotes.

Comment: So it would be even "better" to test for the return value of pidof (which is - according to manpage - 1 if no program was found with the requested name).

Comment: That would be even better indeed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices/#Quoting):

```
if [ -z "$cplane_pid" ]
```

Adding `set -x` before and `set +x` after the command shows you what it results in. For example:

```
$ cplane_pid="1 2 3"
$ set -x
$ [ -z $cplane_pid ]
+ '[' -z 1 2 3 ']'
bash: [: too many arguments
```

In other words, *each* of the whitespace-separated values in the variable was used as a single parameter. Since `-z` requires exactly one parameter, this results in a syntax error.

Rather than saving this as a variable, you can simply do

```
if ! pidof hnb_gw.exe > /dev/null
```

If the process doesn't exist, it will return 1 ("false").

Answer (score 1):

When you execute

```
cplane_pid=`pidof hnb_gw.exe`
```

then `cplane_pid` can contain more (space separated) items.

So the expansion in

```
if [ -z $cplane_pid ]
```

will become

```
if [ -z firstPid secondPid etc ]
```

and that is your error `"[: too many arguments"`

You can solve this with quoting the variable (you should do this ALWAYS in shell)

```
if [ -z "$cplane_pid" ]
```

or use `[[` (if it's installed on your system), which is better in many ways. For instance you don't need to quote variable :)

```
if [[ -z $cplane_pid ]]
```

is the same as

```
if [[ -z "$cplane_pid" ]]
```

For testing purposes (and erros like this) use -x hasbang bash option

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

or use debug sections

```
-- normal code --
set -x # debug section starts here
[ -z $cplane_pid ] && echo zero
eval something
set +x # debug section ends here
-- normal code --
```

also you can call the script

```
/bin/bash -x yourScript.sh
```

Comment: `sh: 2: [[: not found` (ok, in cygwin `/bin/sh` is always bash, so it will work; not so on most unices)

Comment: Tha's why I mentioned more solutions :) jinak zdravim, Honzo :)

Answer (score 0):

pidof can return more than one pid, in these cases, your test will get too many arguments.